# Rails select all users from table where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select all users from a join table and I can't get the query right. 
My Models are User and Goal, which are joined by Participations. I need to list all users from Participations where the goal id = x.

```
@participants = User.joins(:participations).where(goal_id: @goal.parent_id)
```

This is not correct, because I get `no such column: users.goal_id:`. I can't figure out how to select all the users from the join table.

I can use `@participants = @goal.participants` when I'm not trying to use the goal parent id for some reason. When I do this here, I get a `Couldn't find Goal without an ID` error. I'm cool with a solution to either of these issues.

```
if @goal.parent_id?
  @parent_goal = Goal.find(params[@goal.parent_id])
  @participants = @parent_goal.participants
else
  @participants = @goal.participants
end
```

*Goal.rb*

```
  has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, :through => :participations, :source => :user
```

*User.rb*

```
  has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participant_goals, through: :participations, :source => :goal
```

*Participation.rb*

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :goal
```

Comment: Please post your models.

Comment: Updated with models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goal_id column is present in participations table so you need to use following query

```
@participants = User.joins(:participations).where('participations.goal_id = ?', @goal.parent_id)
```

Comment: That was it, much appreciated!